# Any ideas why I cannot download this xlsx by R?

Tags: r

This is the page:
`https://ceegex.hu/en/market-data/daily-data?market_data_day_filter%5BstartDate%5D=2018-03-08&market_data_day_filter%5BendDate%5D=2018-03-30`

where we got "download as xlsx" button.  The address of this button is:
`https://ceegex.hu/en/market_data/day/export.xlsx?startDate=2018-03-08&endDate=2018-03-30&_format=xlsx`

This address downloads a xlsx file. I want to do the same with R so I've written:
`download.file("https://ceegex.hu/en/market_data/day/export.xlsx?startDate=2018-03-08&endDate=2018-03-30&_format=xlsx", "myfile.xlsx")`
but I got errors like `Error in download.file`, `cannot open URL`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file don't exist in the website, this is created when you press the button. Try it using the curl method:

```
download.file("https://ceegex.hu/en/market_data/day/export.xlsx?startDate=2018-03-08&endDate=2018-03-30&_format=xlsx", 
              "myfile.xlsx", method = "curl")
```

Comment: Yes, for me it works. Can you give more details of your operating system and R versions and your packages?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
target = "https://ceegex.hu/en/market_data/day/export.xlsx?startDate=2018-03-08&endDate=2018-03-30&_format=xlsx"
dest = 'downloaded_file.xls'

download.file(url = target, destfile = dest, mode='wb')
```